# Clone row changes effect to the parent row,not to the clone row

Tags: jquery, html

I have a html table below and when I add a new row from clone,I want to remove the first option in select-txtposting of the clone row,but its remove in parent row select-txtposting,not in clone row select-txtposting,how can I do this?

this is the table
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G0Evn.jpg)

In image, Second row is the clone row and I want to remove the first option of posting types in second row from change the input of second row Current issue Quantity,but not changing any values of first (Parent) row.

```
    $("#select-product").change(function () {

        document.getElementById('select-product').disabled = true;

        var mrqno = $("#select-product :selected").val();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/StockTransfer/CallMRN_No?MRNNO=" + mrqno,
            contentType: "application/; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            async: false,
            success: function (grnhdmethod) {
                if (grnhdmethod.length > 0) {
                    var i = 0;

                    $.each(grnhdmethod, function (index, item) {
                        debugger;
                        var row = '<tr>';

                        row += '<td class="ProId" id="idPoNum" style="width: 30px " >' + $(this).attr('ItemId') + '</td>';

                        row += '<td class="MRNNo" id="idMrnNum">' + $(this).attr('MaterialRequest_No') + '</td>';

                        row += '<td class="MRNNo" id="idMrnNum">0</td>';


                        row += '<td class="select-ind" dir="rtl">' +
                            '<select id="select-txtpro' + index + '" class="select-Id" style="width: 100px " dir="ltr" >"<option>--Product--</option>"</select></td>';


                        row += '<td class="BudgetQty" >' + '<input type="text" class="bdgt-qty form-control col-md-3 center-block input-sm" id="bdgt-qty-' + $(this).attr('ItemId') + '" disabled="true" style="width: 75px">' + '</td>';

                        row += '<td class="UnitCode">' + $(this).attr('UnitCode') + '</td>';

                        row += '<td class="UnitPrice">' + $(this).attr('UnitPrice') + '</td>';

                        row += '<td class="ordrQty">' + $(this).attr('Quantity') + '</td>';

                        row += '<td class="allreadyrecived">' + $(this).attr('finalval') + '</td>';

                        row += '<td class="stockval">' + '<input type="text" class="input-stk form-control col-md-3 center-block input-sm" id="input-stk-' + $(this).attr('ItemId') + '" disabled="true">' + '</td>';



                        row += '<td class="totoverissue">' + $(this).attr('TotalOverIssue') + '</td>';

                        row += '<td class="OverIssueQty" id="over-issue" dir="rtl" align="right">0</td>';


                        row += '<td class="select-postype" dir="rtl">' +
                           '<select id="select-txtposting" class="select-PosType" style="width: 75px " dir="ltr" disabled="true"></select>' + '</td>';

                        if ($(this).attr('TotalOverIssue') > 0) {
                            row += '<td class="blncQty" id="bal" dir="rtl" align="right">0</td>';

                        }
                        else {

                            row += '<td class="blncQty" id="bal" dir="rtl" align="right">' + ($(this).attr('Quantity') - $(this).attr('totalrecieve')) + '</td>';
                        }

                        if ($(this).attr('Quantity') <= $(this).attr('totalrecieve')) {
                            row += '<td class="col-md-1 inpqty" dir="rtl">' + '<input type="text" class="input-qty form-control col-md-3 center-block input-sm" data-id="input-qty" disabled="true">' + '</td>';

                            return true;

                        }
                        else {


                            row += '<td class="col-md-1 inpqty" dir="rtl">' + '<input type="text" class="input-qty form-control col-md-3 center-block input-sm" id="input-qty-' + $(this).attr('ItemId') + '" value="0" style="width: 75px " disabled="true">' + '</td>';
                        }
                        row += '<td class="col-md-1 btnadd" dir="rtl">' + '<input type="button" class="AddNew" value="Add" style="width: 50px ">' + '</td>';


                        row += '</tr>';

                        table.append(row);

                        $.each(item.Products, function (i,product) {
                            $('#select-txtpro'+index).append(
                                $("<option></option>")
                                .text((product.ProductName) + ' - ' + (product.SupplierName) + ' - ' + (product.Product_ProductCode))
                                .val(product.ProductId)
                                .attr('ProductId', item.ProductId)
                                .attr('ProductName', item.ProductName)
                            );
                        })

                    });
                }
            }

        });

    });
```

Comment: In image, Second row is the clone row and I want to remove the first option of posting types in second row from change the input of second row Current issue Quantity,but not changing any values of first (Parent) row.

Comment: Help me to do this please!